# Estructura con punteros que "busca" un dato almacenado preestablecido

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Buenas. Tengo un problema con un código que estoy haciendo para un proyecto en c++, el cual necesito buscar en una estructura, en la cual utilizo punteros, un dato en especifico. En este caso es el nombre de una estación de metro o tren. He intentado varias cosas pero ninguna resulta y las respuestas que he visto por internet son estructuras las cuales no usan punteros, y yo necesito usar punteros obligatoriamente en este proyecto.

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    struct datosEstacion{
           char nombre[30];
           int km;
           int precio;

           char nombre2[30];
           int km2;
           int precio2;

           char nombre3[30];
           int km3;
           int precio3;

           char nombre4[30];
           int km4;
           int precio4;

           char nombre5[30];
           int km5;
           int precio5;

           char nombre6[30];
           int km6;
           int precio6;

           };

           struct datosEstacion *linea1;

           linea1=(struct datosEstacion*)malloc(sizeof(struct datosEstacion));
           strcpy (linea1->nombre,"Propatria");
           linea1->km=0;
           linea1->precio=0;

           strcpy (linea1->nombre2,"Agua salud");
           linea1->km2=14;
           linea1->precio2=500;

           strcpy (linea1->nombre3,"La hoyada");
           linea1->km3=21;
           linea1->precio3=1000;

           strcpy (linea1->nombre4,"Bellas Artes");
           linea1->km4=29;
           linea1->precio4=1500;

           strcpy (linea1->nombre5,"Colegio de ingenieros");
           linea1->km5=35;
           linea1->precio5=2000;

           strcpy (linea1->nombre6,"Plaza Venezuela");
           linea1->km6=44;
           linea1->precio6=2500;

           cout<<"***Estaciones del metro de la linea 1***"<<endl;
           cout<<"Nombre:"<<linea1->nombre<<endl;
           cout<<"Kms:"<<linea1->km<<endl;
           cout<<"Precio:"<<linea1->precio<<endl;
           cout<<endl;
           cout<<"Nombre:"<<linea1->nombre2<<endl;
           cout<<"Kms:"<<linea1->km2<<endl;
           cout<<"Precio:"<<linea1->precio2<<endl;
           cout<<endl;
           cout<<"Nombre:"<<linea1->nombre3<<endl;
           cout<<"Kms:"<<linea1->km3<<endl;
           cout<<"Precio:"<<linea1->precio3<<endl;
           cout<<endl;
           cout<<"Nombre:"<<linea1->nombre4<<endl;
           cout<<"Kms:"<<linea1->km4<<endl;
           cout<<"Precio:"<<linea1->precio4<<endl;
           cout<<endl;
           cout<<"Nombre:"<<linea1->nombre5<<endl;
           cout<<"Kms:"<<linea1->km5<<endl;
           cout<<"Precio:"<<linea1->precio5<<endl;
           cout<<endl;
           cout<<"Nombre:"<<linea1->nombre6<<endl;
           cout<<"Kms:"<<linea1->km6<<endl;
           cout<<"Precio:"<<linea1->precio6<<endl;

           cout<<endl;
           cout<<endl;

           string estacion1;
           string estacion2;

           cout<<"Ingrese la estacion uno (punto de partida)"<<endl;
           getline(cin,estacion1);
           cout<<"Ingrese la estacion dos (punto de llegada)"<<endl;  
           getline(cin,estacion2);  

           //aqui se supone es donde va la sentencia que busca "el nombre de la estacion, para luego "juntarlo" con sus otros datos, que son los kms y el precio

           free(linea1);

           system("pause");
           }
```

Había intentado if (estacion1) == (linea1) pero no me resulta ni me funciona. La cosa es que no quiero que me almacene ningun dato (yo ya los tengo preestablecidos), sino que me lo busque en la estructura de punteros o estructura con punteros. Lo que busco es que, después de que el usuario introduzca el nombre de la estación, este vaya ligado con los kms y el precio, para después imprimirle el total que va a pagar y ciertas condiciones más. Agradecería sus respuestas.

Comment: Hola Grecia, haciendo una observacion, podrias optimizar lo que haces haciendo un arreglo de estructuras en vez de varias variables repetidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P. Valero, me parece que no estas haciendo uso de punteros en realidad, y a mi parecer por la forma como estas escribiendo tu código sería muy difícil que lo logres.

En primer lugar como sugerencia te reitero que el uso de `char nombre[30]` es un poco estilo C, incluso para hacer las comparaciones como `strcpy (linea1->nombre2,"Agua salud");` debes incluir la librería `<cstring>` que es como decir cadenas al estilo C. por lo que te sugiero que utilices la librería `<string>` que tiene una gran cantidad de funciones espectaculares para manejar cadenas.

Ademas mezclas peras con manzanas, porque guardas los datos de los nombres de estación como `char[]` y lo que le pides al usuario lo guardas como `string`, por lo que no va a funcionar

Habiendo dicho esto te sugiero usar este codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    struct datosEstacion
    {
        string nombre;
        int km;
        int precio;
    };

    struct datosEstacion *linea1;

           linea1= new datosEstacion[6];// esto es mas estilo c++
           //linea1=(struct datosEstacion*)malloc(sizeof(struct datosEstacion)); // este es mas estilo C

           linea1->nombre ="Propatria"; //esta es una de las ventajas de string sobre cstring asignacion sin uso de strcpy
           linea1->km=0;
           linea1->precio=0;
// Y AQUI EMPIEZAS A USAR EL PUNTERO
// EN VEZ DE TENER QUE GENERAR UNA ESTRUCTURA DE 6 ESTACIONES
// GENERAS UNA ESTRUCTURA DE 1 ESTACION
// Y VAS "APUNTANDO" ESTACION POR ESTACION


           (linea1+1)->nombre="Agua salud";
           (linea1+1)->km=14;
           (linea1+1)->precio=500;

           (linea1+2)->nombre = "La hoyada";
           (linea1+2)->km=21;
           (linea1+2)->precio=1000;
/*
           .
           .
           .
*/

           cout<<"***Estaciones del metro de la linea 1***"<<endl;
           //Esto permitirá mejorar todo tu codigo
           int numEstaciones= 3; //esto porque solo llené tres, luego tu completas con 6
           for (int i=0 ; i < numEstaciones; i++ )
           {
               cout<<"Nombre:"<<(linea1+i)->nombre<<endl;
               cout<<"Kms:"<<(linea1+i)->km<<endl;
               cout<<"Precio:"<<(linea1+i)->precio<<endl;
               cout<<endl;
           }
           cout<<endl;
           cout<<endl;

           string estacion1;
           string estacion2;

           cout<<"Ingrese la estacion uno (punto de partida)"<<endl;
           getline(cin,estacion1);
           cout<<"Ingrese la estacion dos (punto de llegada)"<<endl;  
           getline(cin,estacion2);  

           //aqui se supone es donde va la sentencia que busca "el nombre de la estacion, para luego "juntarlo" con sus otros datos, que son los kms y el precio
            // Pues ahora si usando punteros es posible, de la otra manera era por decirlo imposible
            int estacionUno;
            int estacionDos;
            for (int i=0 ; i < numEstaciones; i++ )
            {
                if(estacion1.compare((linea1+i)->nombre)==0) estacionUno = i;
                if(estacion2.compare((linea1+i)->nombre)==0) estacionDos = i;
            }
             cout <<" estacion 1 es " << (linea1+estacionUno)->nombre << endl;
             cout <<" estacion 2 es " << (linea1+estacionDos)->nombre << endl;
           delete[] linea1;

           system("pause");
 }
```

en los comentarios interno del codigo esta la exlicación.
Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Tengo un problema con un código que estoy haciendo para un proyecto en c++

En ese caso, deberías abandonar la idea de almacenar los nombres de estación en arreglos de tamaño estático, te aconsejo crear una estructura que almacene los datos de estación en un [`std::string`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string):

```
struct Estacion{
    std::string nombre;
    double km;
    double precio;
};
```

Además, los quilómetros y el precio es mejor expresarlos en datos `double` en lugar de enteros, ya que ambos pueden contener decimales.

Una vez tengas definida la estructura `Estacion` puedes almacenar una colección de estaciones, como por ejemplo un [`std::vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<Estacion> datosEstacion = {
    {"Propatria",             0,  0},
    {"Agua salud",            14, 500},
    {"La hoyada",             21, 1000},
    {"Bellas Artes",          29, 1500},
    {"Colegio de ingenieros", 35, 2000},
    {"Plaza Venezuela",       44, 2500},
};
```

Para buscar el nombre de la estación, sería tan sencillo como usar un bucle:

```
std::string estacion1;
std::string estacion2;

std::cout<<"Ingrese la estacion uno (punto de partida)"<<std::endl;
std::getline(std::cin,estacion1);
std::cout<<"Ingrese la estacion dos (punto de llegada)"<<std::endl;  
std::getline(std::cin,estacion2);

for (int indice = 0; indice < datosEstacion.size(); ++indice){
    if (datosEstacion[indice].nombre == estacion1){
        // hemos encontrado estacion1
    }

    if (datosEstacion[indice].nombre == estacion2){
        // hemos encontrado estacion2
    }
}
```

También podrías usar un poco de C++ moderno con [`std::find_if`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) y una [lambda](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
std::string estacion1;
std::string estacion2;

std::cout<<"Ingrese la estacion uno (punto de partida)"<<std::endl;
std::getline(std::cin,estacion1);
std::cout<<"Ingrese la estacion dos (punto de llegada)"<<std::endl;  
std::getline(std::cin,estacion2);

auto e1 = std::find_if(datosEstacion.begin(), datosEstacion.end(),
    [&estacion1](const Estacion &e) {
        return e.nombre == estacion1;
});

auto e2 = std::find_if(datosEstacion.begin(), datosEstacion.end(),
    [&estacion2](const Estacion &e) {
        return e.nombre == estacion2;
});
```

Tras ejecutar el código anterior, `e1` y `e2` serían [iteradores](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) apuntando a el objeto `Estacion` cuyo nombre sea `estacion1` y `estacion2` respectivamente.

[[Aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AN7vQseG0bpVJrkd) puedes ver el código de ejemplo funcionando.